# Checking to see when the next letter in a char is after the period

Tags: java, arrays, char

So I'm writing a program for practice, and I'm a bit stuck. I want to check to see if the first character in a char[] array is a letter, I've tried isLetter, but apparently you can't do that in char.

example sentence: "/my name is chris"
NOTICE THE : "/" at the beginning.

I want to make it so the first LETTER gets capitalized. so it would be

fixed example sentence: "/My name is chris"

My code will most likely be very messy and over-coded, but I'm not to the point to where I can shorten it up, I'm not that advanced yet. Like I said, it most likely will be messy.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class FileOrUserSentenceHandler 
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String userChoice, fileName;
char period = '.';
String s;
String userSentence;




public String getUserChoice()
{

    System.out.println("Would you like the program to read from a file or a sentence from you? Type 'File' for it to read an already-created file, Type 'me' for it to read a sentence from you.");
    userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

    return userChoice;
}

public void decideChoice() throws Exception
{
    if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("file"))
    {
        pickedFile();
    }
    else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("me"))
    {
        pickedMe();
    }
    else
    {
        getUserChoice();
        decideChoice();
    }
}

public void pickedFile() throws Exception
{

    //create file object
    File outFile = new File("CreatedFile.txt");
    BufferedWriter outBWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

    outBWriter.write("you picked the file option. why not pick the 'me' option?");

    //close the file
    outBWriter.close();
    System.out.println("File was created, Data was written to file.");


    try
    {
        File inFile = new File("CreatedFile.txt");

        BufferedReader inBReader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));

        do
        {
            s = inBReader.readLine();
            if(s == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(s);

            System.out.println("Fixing the sentence from the file...");
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();


            for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
            {

                if(i == 0)
                {
                    charArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[i]);
                }

                if(charArray[i] == '.')
                {
                    charArray[i + 2] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[i + 2]);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(charArray);

        }while(s != null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error. Closing program...");
        System.exit(0);
    }


}

public void pickedMe()
{
    System.out.println("You picked the 'me' option. Please enter a sentence below:");
    userSentence = keyboard.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer userSentenceEdited = new StringTokenizer(userSentence, " "); //creates a tokenized String of userSentence, checks the spaces
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while(userSentenceEdited.hasMoreElements())
    {
        sb.append(userSentenceEdited.nextElement()).append(" ");
    }

    userSentence = sb.toString();

    //System.out.println(userSentence); // printed out to check if it was working properly

    outerloop : if((userSentence.charAt(userSentence.length() - 1) != '.'))
    {
            if(userSentence.charAt(userSentence.length() - 1) == ' ')
            {
                userSentence = userSentence.trim();
            }

            if(userSentence.charAt(userSentence.length() - 1) == '.')
            {
                //System.out.println("hello");
                break outerloop;
            }

        userSentence += '.';
    }

    //System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());


    char[] userCharArray = userSentence.toCharArray(); //converts the userSentence to a char[] array

    for(int i = 0; i < userCharArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0) //checks if it's at the beginning of the array, if so, capitalizes it.
        {
            userCharArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(userCharArray[i]);
        }

        if(i == '.') //checks if it's at a period, if so, it checks if it's at the end of the sentence
                                    //if it is, it breaks out of the loop, which means it doesn't capitalize nothing,
                                    //if it's not the end of the String, it capitalizes 2 spaces over.
        {
            if(i == userCharArray.length)
            {
                break;
            }
            userCharArray[i + 2] = Character.toUpperCase(userCharArray[i + 2]);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(userCharArray);
}


}
```

Again, I know it's most likely very messy, I can't stress this enough, I'll be working on it later.

Please be nice, it's my first 'big' program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this...

```
 if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0))){
     //change the first char to upper case
     str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
 }
```

where `str` is the variable name for the string that you are working with

Rather than going through your whole string and always checking where the next letter appears after the period (as it could appear any number of spaces after the period), here is another way to fix your string so that the letters after the period are always capitalized.

```
//split all sentences and put them into an array
String[] tokens = str.trim().split("\\.");
//initialize a result string
String resultString = " ";
//loop through every sentence capitalizing the first character.
for(int i = 0; i<tokens.length; i++){
   //first trim off any whitespace that may occur after period...
   tokens[i] = tokens[i].trim();
   //then capitalize the first letter of every sentence
   tokens[i] = tokens[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + tokens[i].substring(1);
   //then add the sentence with the upperCase first character to your result string
   resultString += " " + tokens[i] + ".";
}
//once out of loop, resultString has the contents of all the sentences with a capital letter to begin the sentence. Notice I use str for my string name, you use s
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, and duh! How could I not try that.. Thanks! Also, I have problem, with the code I have now, if I have multiple '.', it won't capitalize the next letters. It's checking if it's the last character in the array, and it's just breaking out of the for loop. And sorry to bother you one more time, but as you can probably tell, I delete the extra unneeded spaces in the middle, how do I make it so once they're deleted, the next word is capitalized after the period? so like if I used 'hi.   Josh', it would make it 'hi. Josh.'? Sorry to bother so much, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, stupid character limit. Here: So let's say I have a sentence that's either 'hi..' or 'hi.  Josh'(two spaces) and I know the reason, it's because I only do [i + 2], but what I'm wondering is, how do I check to see if the next letter is two spots after the period, if it is, capitalize it, if it's not, make it 2 spots after the period and then capitalize it.

Comment: can you just do something like if(str.charAt(firstIndexAfterPeriod) == ' ' && str.charAt(secondIndexAfterPeriod == ' ') //capitalize str.charAt(thirdIndexAfterPeriod

Comment: I have added a second solution to my answer to help you with the second problem that you had mentioned

Comment: I tried adding that, fixing some of the stuff to match my code, but it's still not capitalizing... Any ideas?

Comment: My bad, I have made several edits to the bottom part of my answer, in the split method use \\. and then the line tokens[i] = tokens[i].trim() is also changed...as well as the final line...I know it works now because I compiled and tried it. Consider accepting my answer for my time by clicking the checkmark if you found this useful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
boolean b = Character.isLetter(arr[0]);
```

where **arr** is an array of chars or

```
boolean b = Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0));
```

if you have a String **s** and not a char array.